# Scrolling issue in collectionView reusable cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

**Scenario**
I have a horizontal collection view with each cell holding a vertical collection view. So basically its an array of products wherein:

1. Horizontal collection view has a datasource of [Product] objects.
2. Vertical collection view(which is inside the cell of horizontal collection view) shows the details of that particular product.

**Issue**
Now the issue is that, let's say, whenever I scroll the first product vertically to some offset to see its details and then goto fourth product(by scrolling horizontally), it shows me scrolled to the same offset as first product due to reusability of cells.

**Possible solutions I tried**

1. Tried resetting the contentoffset to 0 in prepareForReuse().
2. Stored the offsets for each product in an array and then set the offset using willDisplayCell. This solves the offset problem but some components don't load on some products till I scroll a bit.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How about setting the contentoffset to 0 in `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` -https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview

Comment: Then it will be 0 for all cells, even for those that have been scrolled.

Comment: Then keep a track of the offset for that specific product and in willDisplay set the offset instead of 0 as I suggested earlier. If this does not solve this issue, if you can isolate this code on a github repo so that I can run your code at my end, I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: I know is not actually a solution to your problem. But I don't think is a good idea for implementing your UI to have a vertical collection view inside each cell of the horizontal collection view. Why not having just a cell with a stack view or some other solution that doesn't involve having collection view inside collection view?

Comment: GustavoConde The requirement was like that only because there are a lot of recommended products on vertical collectionview as well. So, reusability is required for some components. Hence the collectionview inside a cell.